# dropdownlist first element styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I want to set color of dropdown's first element in jquery/javascript.

Means,whether the first element of dropdown is selected or not that should be in some specific color.

For example:

Let there are 4 elements in dropdown list :-

```
select
Car
Bike
Bus
```

Then the first element(select) should show on some specific color always.

Edit :

[image]

> > According to above image the select filed is colored on the list.But not on the default text.

I want the both.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectboxid option:eq(0)").css("color","red");// you can set any color
```

reference **[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** and **[eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

Comment: Ritu its showing the set color on dropdownlist.But not on the default label of dropdownlist.And i am wondering for that.

Comment: $("#selectboxid option:selected").css("color","red");// you can set any color

Comment: by color only text color change use background at the place of color then  then background change if you want both then use$("#selectboxid option:eq(0)").css({"color":"red","background","#green"});

Comment: this is not a right answer, only changes the dropdown when open it.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

Html:

```
<select id="selectboxid">
<option selected="selected">Hello</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

Js:

```
$("#selectboxid").css("color","green");
$("#selectboxid option").not("#selectboxid :selected").each(function(){
$(this).css("color","black")
});
$("#selectboxid").change(function(){
    $("option",this).each(function(){
    $(this).css("color","black");
    })
    $(":selected",this).css("color","green");
})
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8ELS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ?
( with css )

```
select option:first-child{
    background:red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/PjjmT/

Comment: When you click on select, and you show the drop down list with first option in background red

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can (in some browsers, but not necessarily all, given the difficulties with styling `select` elements reliably), style the `select` option (given the following HTML):

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
    <option value="3">Two</option>
</select>
```

And CSS:

```
option {
    color: #f00;
}

option[value] {
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aYqYF/1/).

The above approach requires the use of a browser that understands attribute-selector notation, of course, and styles `option` elements that have a `value` attribute with the colour `#000`, and those `option` elements *without* the `value` attribute `#f00`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/QnLDn/1/), this is helpfull for you

HTML

```
<select><option>ABC</option><option>CDE</option><option>FGH</option></select>
```

JS

```
$('select option:first-child').css("background-color", 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the way for my task:

$("select option:first-child").css('color', 'gray');

if ($("#SelectedProductId").val() == "0") $("#SelectedProductId").css('color', 'gray');
   else $("#SelectedProductId").css('color', 'black');

$("#SelectedProductId").change(function () {
       if ($("#SelectedProductId").val() == "0") $("#SelectedProductId").css('color', 'gray');
       else $("#SelectedProductId").css('color', 'black');
   });